# Class function passed to onclick attribute is not defined

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to build a class that's somehow modelled to how React classes are made. This is what I have so far:

```
export default class Pagination {
  constructor(attr) {
    const { totalPages } = attr;

    this.totalPages = totalPages;
    this.activePage = 1;
  }

  goToPage(newPageNumber) {
    console.log(newPageNumber);
  }

  render() {
    const pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.totalPages; i++) {
      pages.push(`
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="this.goToPage(${i})" class="${
        i === this.activePage ? 'active' : ''
      }">${i}</a>
        </li>
      `);
    }

    return pages.join('');
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I click a link, it says `this.goToPage is not a function`. How do I properly assign my class' method `goToPage` to the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind `goToPage` to the parent context:

```
constructor(attr) {
   const { totalPages } = attr;

   this.totalPages = totalPages;
   this.activePage = 1;

   this.goToPage = this.goToPage.bind(this);
}
```

However, keep in mind that calling `onclick` in an html element automatically assigns `this` to the elements context. So you'll need to utilize an `eventListenter` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I just tried doing that and I get this error: this.goToPage is not a function

Comment: @JudeMaranga Right. I see what you're doing now. in your case `this` refers to the html element. You'll need to attach an event listener, and call a method when the event is triggered, rather than using the html onclick property.

Comment: when would be the best time to set the event listener to each of the <a>'s? So like I'll create another class method called `setEventListeners` and then after calling `render`, I'll call that method?

Comment: Well, in React I would set the event listeners in componentDidMount(). So I suppose you should try to come up with some kind of logical equivalent to componentDidMount